# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd_extensions.sweetalert'

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am attempting to create an apk with Kivymd using googlecolab. I am following the official instructions from Kivymd. But my apk was crashed.This is my logcat Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd_extensions.sweetalert' .

requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip,pygments,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow,openssl,sqlite3,kivymd_extensions.sweetalert

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some modules which are not easy to install in the buildozer file.
in my experience as i have use sweetalert in a project and it worked, i needed to change some variables of the kivymd_extensions widgets so included the entire kivymd_extensions folder in my project folder hence i didn't have to include in my buildozer file cuz my project ran with the version in the project folder. the kivymd_extensions folder you are adding to your project folder make sure it has the sweetalert folder in it
[image: kivymd_extensions/sweetalert]

and the following code to import
`from kivymd_extensions.sweetalert import SweetAlert`